# How do I get rid of the horizontal scroll bar at the bottom?

Tags: html, css

Please take a look at [this](http://thestrand.spin-demo.com/).

I've tried adjusting the overflow properties and changing the widths of the images but the scroll bar remains at the bottom of the screen.

Does anyone know what is causing this and how to stop this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your `.slideshow` definition (style.css:199...).

The browser tries to solve the formula:

```
left
+ margin-left
+ border-left-width
+ padding-left
+ width
+ padding-right
+ border-right-width
+ margin-right
+ right
= parent width
```

and fails because `left` is 50% and `width` is 100%. Your use of `margin:-800px` won't help on a device with display width of 1920px, as (1920*1.5 - 800) is 2080 and thus too wide for a device of that size.

Use the following definition instead, as it will implicit create a element with an `width` of 100%.

```
.slideshow{
    z-index: -9999;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

See also [CSS Positioned Layout Module Level 3: Section 7.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#abs-non-replaced-width). Keep in mind, that even when you use the technique described above users with a display width of less than 1024px will have a scrollbar. For this issue try `body{overflow-x:hidden;}`.

Your old code (don't use it! only for completion):

```
.slideshow{
    z-index: -9999;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100% !important;
    margin-left: -800px;
}
```

Comment: **Finally somebody gets to the root cause.**  +1... perhaps show the CSS rule at line 199 as well.  It's a jumble...  `left: 50%; margin-left: -800px; etc.`  If one finds themselves using huge negative margins to compensate for something else, maybe the original method needs to be re-examined from scratch.

Comment: @Sparky672: Included old code and also added a little bit of explanation. I don't really know why so many people try to use too simple hacks (no offense to you guys), when the problem is clearly somewhere between the fragile lines of what could be precious css code...

Comment: I think it's always best to know _why_ you have to do something rather than this blanket approach of resetting all CSS rules and hiding overflows.  Seriously, think about it... you essentially "reset" the default CSS every time you apply your own rule.  It's ridiculous to apply `margin: 0;` to `p` when three lines later, you're only applying your own margin to `p`.

Comment: Zeta, I thought this would fix it but it basically miss-aligns the background (.slideshow). Could you take a look?

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior, sorry. Since this is a new problem (which could be unrelated to this question) ask a new question to raise awareness.

Answer (score 1):

This should get rid of it, just tried in devtools.

```
body { overflow-x: hidden; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
overflow-x:hidden; 
overflow-y:auto;
```

should do it.

or to be on the safe side, to cover browsers that might not support that:

```
overflow:auto; 
overflow-x:hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as Mr. Pallazzo said, but this will chop off all content to the right side (that you're now having to scroll to see) which you probably don't want. Please take a good look instead at the width specifications of the wrapper divs etc. Your div called `wraper` has a `width` set as 1003px. It is best not to set dimensions in such absolute terms, and instead use percentages.